# I can't access response body Cypress Api Testing

Tags: api, cypress, web-api-testing

I want to automate the api using Cypress, but I can't access the response body.

Use this path cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body.payload[0]

Api Response

[image]

Code

```js
  context('GET /Auth', () => {
    it('should return a list with all products', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://auth.plus.a101.com.tr/api/homepage/punch-cards/20149126',
            headers: {
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
              expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
              cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body.payload[0]))
            });
    });
});
```

I get error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `response.body.payload.0` instead of `response.body.payload[0]`?

Comment: Hi. I suppose, that response is returned with delay even if the status code is in place, so when you try to log it, the response is not returned yet. Could you just: `cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body.payload))` and check if the payload is as you expect to be?

Comment: @AlexIzbas I tired but log is empty no error interesting.

Comment: @jjhelguero doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

You have to convert your response object a json string and then parse it. Instead you can try the following:

```
  cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://auth.plus.a101.com.tr/api/homepage/punch-cards/20149126',
            headers: {
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token
            }
        }).then((response) => {
    response = JSON.stringify(response)
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response)
    cy.log(response.body.payload[0])
});
```

Comment: I _think_ that it is only the `response.body` that will need to be parsed here -> `let jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body)` should suffice.